# How to forward network packets sent by application to different Network Connection or NIC using C#?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I am trying to make a software in C# that can help to use all available network connection and download file or browse websites with the combine speed of all network connection as project. I have gone through various books and website to get some answers about how to use multiple internet connection in c#. But i haven't got the answers.

Software like IDM uses multiple connection to download file. I was thinking to capture request sent by IDM and distribute it equally to all available Network Interfaces.

Can somebody tell me some api that can create virtual network connection and can manipulate network packets and forward the packets through multiple internet connection. I want to create a virtual network adapter like in Private Tunnel (a OpenVPN software) and solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Http protocol to download the files?

Comment: Yes, i was trying to work on HTTP protocol only at the moment. If i try to download a file from IDM, then my software should manage the connection sent by IDM and distribute it equally to all available network interface.